# Are the Black Terror and Knight-Wing based on any pre-existing fictional superheroes?

Tags: short-stories, inspiration, super-hero, thaddeus-howze

I just read the short story ["The Black Terror Rides Again"](https://medium.com/short-sci-fi-stories/the-black-terror-rides-again-ec23e1651ef3) by Thaddeus Howze. It's just a few-minutes read and much more interesting if you learn about the characters bit by bit through the story, so do go and read it before checking this spoilertag:

> There was once a superhero called the Black Terror, with his sidekick/son Knight-Wing, who was the scourge of Chicago criminals for twenty years. Slowly his superhuman powers receded with age, and he became more ruthless and disproportionate. The Justice Legion recruited his son and he continued alone, until his son had to take him down as he'd become more of a supervillain than a superhero. Now both of them live together, but the Black Terror still wants to go out and fight crime, under his new guise as the Sand Man. The Justice Legion were never able to catch him and bring him in.

I don't know much about superhero fiction, all the Marvel and DC characters and so on, but Thaddeus Howze does. Did he base his characters in this story on some existing superheroes in the literature? Does this storyline bear some striking similarities to a specific Marvel/DC story, for example, or is it completely his own innovation?

Comment: Well, his outfit (in the picture) is a direct ripoff of the Punisher's trademark t-shirt.

Comment: The sidekick who wants to go solo and leaves his partner sounds like it is inspired by Dick Grayson, who left his role as Batman's sidekick and went solo under the name Nightwing.

Comment: @BjornEriksson - Aye. The whole thing is a mish-mash of superhero tropes

Comment: Arguably it is impossible to create a superhero today that isn't inspired by some of the thousands of superheroes that have been created before, unless the new author hasn't read any superhero comics.

Comment: @Valorum To me, the Terror looks more like the Phantom.